# sql Column with multiple values (query implementation in a cpp file )

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, sql-server, eclipse

I am using [this](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-capi-tutorial.html) link.

I have connected my cpp file with Eclipse to my Database with 3 tables (two simple tables 
`Person` and `Item`
and a third one `PersonItem` that connects them). In the third table I use one simple primary and then two foreign keys like that:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonsItems(PersonsItemsId int not null auto_increment primary key,
Person_Id int not null,
Item_id int not null,
constraint fk_Person_id foreign key (Person_Id) references Person(PersonId),
constraint fk_Item_id  foreign key (Item_id) references Items(ItemId));
```

So, then with embedded sql in c I want a Person to have multiple items.

My code:

```
   mysql_query(connection, \
   "INSERT INTO PersonsItems(PersonsItemsId, Person_Id, Item_id) VALUES (1,1,5), (1,1,8);");

    printf("%ld PersonsItems Row(s) Updated!\n", (long) mysql_affected_rows(connection));

   //SELECT newly inserted record.
   mysql_query(connection, \
   "SELECT Order_id FROM PersonsItems");

   //Resource struct with rows of returned data.
   resource = mysql_use_result(connection);

   // Fetch multiple results
   while((result = mysql_fetch_row(resource))) {
       printf("%s %s\n",result[0], result[1]);
   }
```

My result is

```
-1 PersonsItems Row(s) Updated!
5
```

but with `VALUES (1,1,5), (1,1,8);`

I would like that to be

```
-1 PersonsItems Row(s) Updated!
5 8
```

Can somone tell me why is this not happening?
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is because your first insert is failing with the following error:

```
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Because you are trying to insert `1` twice into the `PersonsItemsId` which is the primary key so has to be unique (it is also auto_increment so there is no need to specify a value at all);

This is why rows affected is -1, and why in this line:

```
printf("%s %s\n",result[0], result[1]);
```

you are only seeing `5` because the first statement failed after the values `(1,1,5)` had already been inserted, so there is still one row of data in the table.

I think to get the behaviour you are expecting you need to use the [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO PersonsItems(PersonsItemsId, Person_Id, order_id) 
VALUES (1,1,5), (1,1,8)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Person_id = VALUES(person_Id), Order_ID = VALUES(Order_ID);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/634d45/1)**

Or do not specify the value for personsItemsID and let auto_increment do its thing:

```
INSERT INTO PersonsItems( Person_Id, order_id) 
VALUES (1,5), (1,8);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/704db8/1)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo or mistake in your two queries.

You are inserting "PersonsItemsId, Person_Id, Item_id"

```
INSERT INTO PersonsItems(PersonsItemsId, Person_Id, Item_id) VALUES (1,1,5), (1,1,8)
```

and then your select statement selects "Order_id".

```
SELECT Order_id FROM PersonsItems
```

In order to achieve 5, 8 as you request, your second query needs to be:

```
SELECT Item_id FROM PersonsItems
```

**Edit to add:**

Your primary key is `autoincrement` so you don't need to pass it to your insert statement (in fact it will error as you pass 1 twice).

You only need to insert your other columns:

```
INSERT INTO PersonsItems(Person_Id, Item_id) VALUES (1,5), (1,8)
```

Comment: No, I am sorry that was not important. I use Item_id everywhere. It is the same. I am sorry for this. Edited.